# Removing a binding from evil-collection

Tags: key-bindings, evil, gnus

[evil-collection](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection) is mostly quite useful - but occasionally the default settings shadow my global bindings and I seem to need to restart emacs to remove the binding.

I bit up against this problem with the bindings for gnus.

The problematic binding is

```
 ","         'gnus-summary-best-unread-article
```

Set by

```
  (evil-collection-define-key 'normal 'gnus-summary-mode-map
```

in `evil-collection-gnus-setup`.

How can I get rid of this binding without restarting emacs?

## What I've tried

I tried both these function calls:

```
(evil-define-minor-mode-key 'normal 'gnus-summary-mode-map "," nil)
(evil-define-key 'normal 'gnus-summary-mode-map " " nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this to re-map Evil collection keys, this is just a small snippet:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-collection
  (evil-collection-define-key 'normal 'gnus-summary-mode-map
    "," nil))
```

To get rid of the key binding without restarting Emacs, just evaluate the `evil-collection-define-key` part.

Comment: Thanks. This answer gave me enough certainty to some more digging. In the case of gnus there were a few different modes. So I did `M-x eval-expression` `major-mode` and found out that I needed to define a binding in `gnus-group-mode-map`.